# User Archive page for Custom Post Type - Pagination Issue

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pagination

I'm working on the author.php page and showing custom post types created by that user. Everything's working great except the pagination. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (1 == ($paged = (get_query_var('paged') ?: 1))): ?>
    <section class="posts-container">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Posts from <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author ); ?></h2>

            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => array( 'style' ),
                'post_type'      => array( 'travel' ),
                'posts_per_page' => 1000,
                'author'         => $author,
                'paged'=>$paged,
            );
            $author_videos = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : while ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : $author_videos->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part('partials/single', 'post'); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="nav-previous alignleft">
                    <?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-next alignright">
                    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?>
                </div>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query, don't create a new query in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me an example I don't understand I'm afraid?

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried this way?

```
<section class="posts-container">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">Posts from <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author ); ?></h2>

        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => array( 'style', 'travel' ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'author'         => $author
        );

        $author_videos = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : while ( $author_videos->have_posts() ) : $author_videos->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
              // I think you should use archive rather than single
              // get_template_part('partials/archive', 'post');
                 get_template_part('partials/single', 'post');
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="nav-previous alignleft">
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-next alignright">
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?>
            </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The archive partial doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: Does pagination work using the single template?

Comment: Unfortunately not